# index for ArrayField in postgresql(django)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, indexing

I'm using postgresql in Django and also I have an ArrayField in one of my models like follows :

```
words = ArrayField(
    models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True),
    null=True,
    blank=True
)
```

In my code I have queries on this field only for null values. It means I have only following queries on this field :

```
Entity.objects.filter(words__isnull=True).all()
Entity.objects.filter(words__isnull=False).all()
```

Unfortunately table of `Entity` is large and this query takes long hours to answer. What is best index for this field based on my queries?

Comment: Without digging into how to do this in Django, in PostgreSQL this is a good intro to Array fields which talks about setting up GIN and GIST indexes for array columns. https://www.compose.com/articles/take-a-dip-into-postgresql-arrays/

Comment: why don't you use default list value in your words field?

Comment: @MatthewStory Thanks. It was really awesome

Comment: @seuling My field is nullable no need for default value

Comment: I mean you can use blank `list()` for default value

Comment: @seuling I don't want default value. For me null value is different with list()